# Equivalence of transversality conditions

Tags: limits, control-theory

Suppose the following transversality condition:

$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}\lambda(t)\left [x(t)-x_*(t)\right] \geq 0 \quad (1)$

This condition holds for all feasible solutions $x(t)$, while $x_*(t)$ denotes the optimal solution of an optimal control problem.

Furthermore consider now, that $\lambda(t)>0$ and $x(t)\geq 0$ for all times $t$.

Under this additional assumptions i want to show that (1) is equivalent to the following conditions:

$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\lambda(t)x_*(t)=0, \qquad \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\lambda(t)\geq 0. \quad (2)$

I have shown the implication $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$, but I am struggling with the inverse implication. Any ideas?

My problem here is following: I want dot split (1) the following way:

$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\lambda(t)\left[x(t)-x_*(t)\right]\!=\!\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\lambda(t)x(t)-\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\lambda(t)x_*(t)$

But how do i know, that the terms on the righthandside exists and that these are not of the form $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: Wouldn't your assumption of $\lambda(t)>0$ for all times $t$ imply that $(2)$ is equivalent to $$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}x_*(t)=0?$$

Comment: No. $x_*(t)$ Could be increasing over Time, While $\lambda(t)$ is decreasing faster for Example. In this case the Limit of $x_*(t)$ Could also be a Constant. By the Way, i solved this Problem in the  Meanwhile. But thanks for your Comment.